# How do you block users on Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase for my app and was wondering how to block certain users. I see on the Auth tab of the console, there are "delete" and "disable" options. What do those do? I haven't been able to find documentation on that. Will one of those allow me to block a user?

What I mean by blocking a user is for the `".read": "auth != null"` rule to prevent him from accessing data on the database

Comment: Hey @PhilipSopher, let me know if my answer was not clear or you still have any other concern. thanks!

Comment: @adolfosrs Thanks for the answer. I have two questions:

1) How would the `blockedUsers` node look? Is it an array, dictionary, etc? Could you provide a code example?

2) Does the **disable** feature unauthenticate a user that is currently logged in?

Comment: Just updated the answer with additional information for the **first question**. Regarding the **second question**, this will depends if you are constantly reauthenticating users on your implementation . If there is a critical event you want to cover you could `reauthenticate` to handle it. Otherwise you wont unauth.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The **disable** feature consist in preventing that user to authenticate. So if he tries to authenticate he will fail with error code `INVALID_CREDENTIALS` and he won't have access to the data that has the `".read": "auth != null"` rule. It works like he is deleted but the admin still have the power to reactivate the user account.

If you want to build a list of "blocked users" that will be **able to authenticate but will have restricted access**, you can store the blocked ids in a node on your firebase database like `/databaseRoot/blockedUsers` and then work with the `security and rules`.

```
".read": "auth != null && !root.child('blockedUsers').hasChild(auth.uid)"
```

---

**blockedUsers** could look like the tree bellow but you could also add some other info under the userId such as the date this user was blocked.

```
/databaseRoot
    /blockedUsers
       userId1 : true
       userId2 : true
```

Adding the user to this list will depend on your necessity. You can do it manually by accessing the firebase console and adding the user id to the node. Or, if you want to block an user based on an event on the application, you could simply call something like

```
ref.child('blockedUsers').child(userIdToBlock).set(true);
```

Comment: I am looking for something similar. I want to not even allow the users to authenticate to my application. So I want to have a "white list" of users, and all the others not to have access to the application. How can I do this?