# Firebase Authentication for purchased email account only?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have free version and paid version on play store both have firebase authentication how to make sure not login for other email accounts except the account purchased

Comment: They can login but you can stop them for accesing database.

Comment: how to get the purchased email account

Comment: create a seperate list of users who are not paid

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908795/how-do-you-block-users-on-firebase

Comment: my doubt is if you are purchasing the paid app on play store with abc@gmail.com how to get the email abc@gmail.com

Comment: You have implemented In-App purchase ?

Comment: no both are separate apps on play store

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161806/discussion-between-rajesh-vinew-and-abdevelopers).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863113/android-get-google-play-account-associated-with-in-app-billing
*******answer is here ****

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using custom user claims and then enforcing access via Firebase rules or checking the presence of the custom claims in the ID token if you are parsing it in your own server:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

After a user signs in and completes their purchase, you can send the purchase credentials to your backend to process it along with the user's ID token. If both are verified, you set the custom claim for that user:

`admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {paidSubscriber: true}).then(() => {...`

You then force the client to refresh their token to get the latest claims:
`currentUser.getIDToken(true)...`

Now every request can check the user is authorized or not by checking the ID token.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "paidContent": {
      ".read": "auth.token.paidSubscriber === true",
      ".write": "auth.token.paidSubscriber === true",
    }
  }
}
```