# How can I block users in flutter chat app [firebase]

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I'm new with flutter
How can I block users in chat app using flutter and firebase..
What is the functionality ?

I have no idea.

Comment: If you are using Firebase as your Authentication/Authorization back-end than you should change your database a little. Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37909567/7149247

Comment: Could you show your progress? This question has barely any info or showing what you tried it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for helping.
I used this code for block and unblock users.
It works.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

    class Chat with ChangeNotifier {
    // Block a user
      void blockUser({String blockedUserId, String currentUserId}) async {
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('blockedUsers')
            .doc(currentUserId)
            .collection('list')
            .doc(blockedUserId)
            .set({'blockedUserId': blockedUserId}).then((_) async {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: 'Kullancıyı engellediniz..',
            fontSize: 18,
          );
    
          notifyListeners();
        });
        ;
      }
    
    // Check if a user is blocked
      Future<bool> isUserBlocked({String blockedUserId, String currentUserId}) {
        // Return true if the blocked user ID is present in the current user's "blockedUsers" collection
        // You can use this function to disable chat functionality for blocked users
        return FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('blockedUsers')
            .doc(currentUserId)
            .collection('list')
            .doc(blockedUserId)
            .get()
            .then((value) => value.exists);
      }
    
    // Unblock a user
      void unblockUser({String blockedUserId, String currentUserId}) async {
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('blockedUsers')
            .doc(currentUserId)
            .collection('list')
            .doc(blockedUserId)
            .delete()
            .then((_) async {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: 'Engellemeyi Kaldırdınız',
            fontSize: 18,
          );
    
          notifyListeners();
        });
      }
```